# Using ArcGIS sdk 10.2.2 for Android with gradle

Tags: arcgis-10.2, android, arcgis-android

Has anyone got the [ArcGIS SDK](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/) from Esri to work with Android Studio(gradle)?. So far I have the done the following

1. Extracted the ArcGIS Android SDK(10.2.2).
2. Added the .so files (armeabi-v7a & x86) to the jniLibs folder as per this guide
   http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/
3. Added arcgis-android-api.jar, arcgis-android-app-toolkit.jar, jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.5.jar, jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.5 and jcifs-1.3.17.jar to the libs folder

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

productFlavors {


    armv7 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }

    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
    }


}




packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'

}
```

}

**A Screenshot of my Project Structure**

[image: Here is a screenshot of my project structure]

The gradle file compiles successfully but when I  run the application it crashes with the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with
>   name='requestRender' signature='(Z)V' in class
>   Lcom/esri/android/map/MapSurface

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Your are not loading the *.jar dependencies in your build:

`dependencies {
    // local binary dependency
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}`

We now have EAP release of ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android samples [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-android-sdk-gradle-samples) and the v10.2.3 EAP library module [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-android-api-lib-module)